# Unable to use Custom .dll (C#) from C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, c++-cli

Thanks In advance for you time and Help.

**Goal**: I am trying to use my C# library within a C++ project

**What I did**:

1. Created a simple .dll file with my C# project. named: ClassLibrary1.dll
2. Created a C++ console application named: CppClr (Common Language RunTime Support Changed to: /clr)
3. Copied ClassLibrary1.dll to the root off CppClr project

Following is my ClassLibrary1(C#) code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void output()
        {

            String mystr; 


            mystr = "Helloo World"; // create a new string

            Console.WriteLine(mystr);
            Console.WriteLine("From C++ Managed Code!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The Following is my C++/CLI code:

```
#include "CppClr.h"
#using <ClassLibrary1.dll>

int main()
{
    ClassLibrary1::Class1::output();
}
```

**Problem:** The error I get when I run my C++/CLI code :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you need to include the .dll into any project references in your C++ project?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean...

Comment: See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84deabaa-ae82-47cc-aac0-592f5a8dfa22/linking-an-external-dll?forum=Vsexpressvc   

I do not believe that having the .dll on the root folder level would be enough. There should be a way in your solution to right click and include references > Browse > find your .dll and include it in your solution.

Comment: The solution proposes the I need to also include .lib file with the .dll file. However, When I created the ClassLibrary1 it only produced ClassLibrary1.dll and ClassLibrary1.pdb, no .lib file were produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply an issue of your C++ executable not being able find/load the C# DLL at runtime.

There are a few different places that the .NET runtime looks to load assemblies. The simplest of these is from the same directory that your compiled application is running from. It is not enough to have `ClassLibrary1.dll` in the root of your C++ project - it needs to be in same directory that your project is running from.

As a quick and dirty test, you should be able to verify this by copying `ClassLibrary1.dll` into the C++ project's output directory. If you're running in the Debug configuration, this will probably be something like `C:\Projects\CppClr\Debug\` or wherever your C++ project is. Verify that this is the directory that contains the compiled `CppClr.exe` file. Once you copy the DLL here and run your project, the runtime should be able to find the DLL and all should be good.

However, this could be kind of a pain if you're frequently updating your C# project, since you'll continually need to copy it to the C++ output folder every time something changes. The solution to this is to add a *reference* in the C++ project to your C# library.

In Visual Studio, open up your C++ project. From the solution explorer, right-click on **references** and select **Add reference...** Next, click on the **Browse...** button at the bottom of the dialog and browse to the location of `ClassLibrary1.dll` on your disk. Click on **Add** and then **OK**.

Now, whenever you build the C++ project, it will copy the `ClassLibrary1.dll` assembly into the project's output folder. You should also be able to remove the `#using <ClassLibrary1.dll>` directive from the top of your C++ file, since adding the DLL as a project reference should perform the same function.

Comment: Hey Ben, Thank you for your advice, I am not able to test this for the moment because it's on my work computer but i will confirm if this works tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Ben, I've added my .dll file in the folder where .exe file lives and it still does not find it. It gives the following error: `error C1107: could not find assembly 'ClassLibrary1.dll': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable`

Comment: Well, actually now you're getting a _compile time_ error whereas before you had a _runtime_ error. It seems like your C++ project root is configured as part of the assembly search path. To fix this, place one copy of `ClassLibrary1.dll` in the project root (as it was before). This lets the _compiler_ find the assembly, with the help of the `#using` directive in your code. Then make sure there is a **second** copy in the directory with the executable at runtime.

The alternative to this is to add the C# project as a proper reference as I describe in the second part of my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The msdn link shared by Chad is of the case when you want to add a dll created from C++ project.

What you need to do is to create a strong name for your C# library.

- To create a strong name for your class library, type the following command at the Visual Studio .NET command prompt:
  sn.exe -k MyKeyFile.SNK
- Copy the MyKeyFile.SNK file to your project folder.
- Double-click the AssemblyInfo.cs file to open the file in Solution Explorer.
- Replace the following lines of code in the AssemblyInfo.cs file

  ```
  [assembly: ComVisible(false)]
  [assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
  [assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("")]
  ```

with

```
    [assembly: ComVisible(true)] 
    [assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)] 
    [assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("..\\..\\MyKeyFile.SNK")]
```

- Press CTRL+SHIFT+B to generate the managed DLL.
- Now register the managed DLL for use with COM or with Native C++
- Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code or using it.

The link here is close to what the OP is trying to do.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

Comment: my access is denied to `sn.exe -k MyKeyFile.SNK`. I guess this needs to be run as Administrator? This is a company computer and I do not have admin rights. Would there be another way?

Comment: In that case you will need to gain access to at least this one folder.
I am guessing its a windows 7 system.
"C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"
This is where the default key container is , which is used by sn tool.

Comment: I do have access to the folder but when I run the command you stated above, I get: `Failed to create MyKeyFile.SNK -- Access Denied` I believe I cannot output the file in this folder, is there a way to specify where to output the file?

Comment: I should have specified fully, by access I mean, check what privileges do you have on that one folder. Right click on the MachineKeys folder->Select Properties->Go to Security Tab, check if  your username is part of the Group which has the Read & execute privileges.
And if you dont, then contact whatever IT helpdesk you have and ask them to provide you with read and execute rights on that one folder.

Comment: If the C++ project is compiled with CLR support as is stated in the original question, there is no reason to register the C# library with COM as this answer suggests. I think the confusion stems from the fact that the title states "Native C++", in which case COM would be a likely solution. However, this is definitely Managed C++, which should be able to load a C# .NET DLL directly.

Comment: I think the link has a note at the very end , which says you need the CLR support while compiling otherwise it wont compile, so I think registering with COM is still needed. And just compiling with CLR wont suffice.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by specifying the absolute path of the dll file.

before:

```
#using "ClassLibrary1.dll"
```

after:

```
#using "C:\user\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll"
```

if this works for you, you need to go to **Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> "Resolve #using References"** and add the path here. then you can use `#using "ClassLibrary1.dll"` again in your could without the complete path.

Answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179382/error-c1107-could-not-find-assembly-please-specify-the-assembly-search-path-usin)

Comment: Putting absolute paths in your compiled binary isn't the best practice. But if you don't care about maintainability, it's a way to go.